# C# Calculate Combinations from Multiple Lists of Custom Objects with No Repetition

Tags: c#, list, recursion, combinations

So I have been struggling to find a way to create all combinations with no repetition from multiple lists containing custom objects. There are some additional constraints that make it a bit more challenging, of course.

Basically I am parsing a bunch of data from a .csv file that contains part information. This data is then passed on to a custom object and then those objects are added to lists based on their "group." (See code below)

So once the information has been parsed I now have 6 lists containing any number of elements. Now I need to generate all combinations between those 6 lists following these rules:

1. One object from groupA
2. Two objects from groupB (no repetition)
3. Three objects from groupC (no repetition)
4. One object from groupD
5. One object from groupE
6. One object from groupF

These objects are then used to create a ModuleFull object, and my overall end result should be a `List<ModuleFull>` containing all the combinations generated from the part lists.

I was able to figure out a way to do this using LINQ although I did not test it using lists of custom objects because I realized my lists all contain different numbers of elements.

So any help that I could get in coming up with a method to solve this using recursion would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the code parsing the data:

```
            using (TextFieldParser parser = new TextFieldParser(@"c:\temp\test.csv"))
        {
            parser.TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited;
            parser.SetDelimiters(",");

            while (!parser.EndOfData)
            {  
                string[] fields = parser.ReadFields();

                Part tempPart = new Part(fields[0], fields[2], fields[1], double.parse(fields[4]), long.parse(fields[3]));

                allParts.Add(tempPart);

                if (tempPart.group == "A")
                {
                    aParts.Add(tempPart);
                }
                else if (tempPart.group == "B")
                {
                    bParts.Add(tempPart);
                }
                else if (tempPart.group == "C")
                {
                    cParts.Add(tempPart);
                }
                else if (tempPart.group == "D")
                {
                    dParts.Add(tempPart);
                }
                else if (tempPart.group == "E")
                {
                    eParts.Add(tempPart);
                }
                else if (tempPart.group == "F")
                {
                    fParts.Add(tempPart);
                }
            }
```

Below are the two classes for the objects that fill the lists:

```
    public class Part
    {
        public string idNum; //0 locations when being parsed
        public string name; //2
        public string group; //1
        public double tolerance; //4
        public long cost; //3

        public Part(string id, string nm, string grp, double tol, long cst)
        {
            idNum = id;
            name = nm;
            group = grp;
            tolerance = tol;
            cost = cst;
        }
    }

    public class ModuleFull
    {
        public Part groupA;
        public Part groupBOne;
        public Part groupBTwo;
        public Part groupCOne;
        public Part groupCTwo;
        public Part groupCThree;
        public Part groupD;
        public Part groupE;
        public Part groupF;

        public ModuleFull(Part a, Part b1, Part b2, Part c1, Part c2, Part c3, Part d, Part e, Part f)
        {
            groupA = a;
            groupBOne = b1;
            groupBTwo = b2;
            groupCOne = c1;
            groupCTwo = c2;
            groupCThree = c3;
            groupD = d;
            groupE = e;
            groupF = f;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below uses a custom enumerator to get unique combinations.  Very clean solution.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace IEnumerable_IEnumerator_Recursive
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.csv";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Parser parser = new Parser(FILENAME);
            int level = 0;
            List<Part> root = new List<Part>();
            Part.Recurse(level, root);
        }
    }
    public class Parser
    {
        public Boolean EndOfData = false;

        public Parser(string filename)
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filename);
            string inputLine = "";
            while ((inputLine = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                inputLine = inputLine.Trim();
                if (inputLine.Length > 0)
                {
                    string[] fields = inputLine.Split(new char[] { ',' });

                    Part tempPart = new Part(fields[0], fields[1], fields[2], fields[3], fields[4]);

                    Part.allParts.Add(tempPart);
                }
            }
            Part.MakeDictionary();
        }

    }
    public class PartEnumerator : IEnumerator<List<Part>>
    {
        List<Part> parts = null;

        public static SortedDictionary<string, int> maxCount = new SortedDictionary<string, int>() {
            {"A", 1},
            {"B", 2},
            {"C", 3},
            {"D", 1},
            {"E", 1},
            {"F", 1}
        };
        public int size = 0;
        List<int> enumerators = null;

        public PartEnumerator(string name, List<Part> parts)
        {

            this.parts = parts;
            size = maxCount[name];
            enumerators = new List<int>(new int[size]);
            Reset();
        }

        object IEnumerator.Current
        {
            get
            {
                return Current;
            }
        }

        public List<Part> Current
        {
            get
            {
                try
                {
                    List<Part> returnParts = new List<Part>();
                    foreach (int enumerator in enumerators)
                    {
                        returnParts.Add(parts[enumerator]);
                    }

                    return returnParts;
                }
                catch (IndexOutOfRangeException)
                {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException();
                }
            }
        }

        public void Reset()
        {
            for (int count = 0; count < enumerators.Count; count++)
            {
                enumerators[count] = count;
            }
        }

        public Boolean MoveNext()
        {
            Boolean moved = true;
            int listSize = parts.Count;
            int enumNumbers = enumerators.Count;

            //only use enumerators up to the size of list
            if (listSize < enumNumbers)
            {
                enumNumbers = listSize;
            }

            Boolean ripple = true;
            int enumCounter = enumNumbers;
            if (enumCounter > 0)
            {
                while ((ripple == true) && (--enumCounter >= 0))
                {
                    ripple = false;
                    int maxCount = listSize - (enumNumbers - enumCounter);
                    if (enumerators[enumCounter] >= maxCount)
                    {
                        ripple = true;

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        for (int i = enumCounter; i < enumNumbers; i++)
                        {
                            if (i == enumCounter)
                            {
                                enumerators[i] += 1;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                enumerators[i] = enumerators[i - 1] + 1;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                if ((enumCounter <= 0) && (ripple == true))
                {
                    moved = false;
                }

            }

            return moved;
        }
        public void Dispose()
        {
        }

    }
    public class Part
    {

        public static List<Part> allParts = new List<Part>();
        public static Dictionary<string, PartEnumerator> partDict = new Dictionary<string, PartEnumerator>();


        public string idNum; //0 locations when being parsed
        public string name; //2
        public string group; //1
        public double tolerance; //4
        public long cost; //3

        public Part()
        {
        }
        public Part(string id, string nm, string grp, string tol, string cst)
        {
            idNum = id;
            name = nm;
            group = grp;
            tolerance = double.Parse(tol);
            cost = long.Parse(cst);
        }

        public static void MakeDictionary()
        {
            var listPartEnum = Part.allParts.GroupBy(x => x.name)
                .Select(x => new { Key = x.Key, List = new PartEnumerator(x.Key, x.ToList()) });

            foreach (var partEnum in listPartEnum)
            {
                partDict.Add(partEnum.Key, partEnum.List);
            }
        }

        public static string[] NAMES = { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F" };
        public static void Recurse(int level, List<Part> results)
        {
            Boolean moved = true;
            if (level < PartEnumerator.maxCount.Keys.Count)
            {
                //level is equivalent to names in the Part Enumerator dictionary A to F
                string name = NAMES[level];
                PartEnumerator enumerator = partDict[name];
                enumerator.Reset();
                while ((enumerator != null) && moved)
                {
                    List<Part> allParts = new List<Part>(results);
                    allParts.AddRange((List<Part>)enumerator.Current);
                    int currentLevel = level + 1;
                    Recurse(currentLevel, allParts);
                    moved = enumerator.MoveNext();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                string message = string.Join(",", results.Select(x => string.Format("[id:{0},name:{1}]", x.name, x.idNum)).ToArray());
                Console.WriteLine(message);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I used following input file

```
1,A,X,0,0
2,A,X,0,0
3,A,X,0,0
4,A,X,0,0
5,A,X,0,0
1,B,X,0,0
2,B,X,0,0
3,B,X,0,0
4,B,X,0,0
5,B,X,0,0
1,C,X,0,0
2,C,X,0,0
3,C,X,0,0
4,C,X,0,0
5,C,X,0,0
1,D,X,0,0
2,D,X,0,0
3,D,X,0,0
4,D,X,0,0
5,D,X,0,0
1,E,X,0,0
2,E,X,0,0
3,E,X,0,0
4,E,X,0,0
5,E,X,0,0
1,F,X,0,0
2,F,X,0,0
3,F,X,0,0
4,F,X,0,0
5,F,X,0,0
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved with two related methods. One is a method to generate all combinations of items from a list. This deals with your cases where you want more than one from a set, like group B and C. The other is a method to get you all the ways to combine one element from each list, which is otherwise known as a *Cartesian product* and is, in a way, a special case of the first method.

I recently wrote a library of combinatorial functions that includes both of these, so I can share my implementation with you. My library [is on Github](https://github.com/anaximander23/Anaximander.Linq) if you want to look at the source code, and can be [installed from NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Anaximander.Linq/) if you'd like. (The examples below are slightly simplified to fit your situation; in my fuller versions, the combinations method has different modes that allow you to specify whether it matters what order the output items are in, and whether it's allowed to use source items more than once. Neither are needed here, so they've been omitted.)

So, the first of those methods looks something like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Combinations<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int combinationSize)
{
    if (combinationSize > source.Count())
    {
        return new List<IEnumerable<T>>();
    }

    if (source.Count() == 1)
    {
        return new[] { source };
    }

    var indexedSource = source
        .Select((x, i) => new
        {
            Item = x,
            Index = i
        })
        .ToList();

    return indexedSource
        .SelectMany(x => indexedSource
            .OrderBy(y => x.Index != y.Index)
            .Skip(1)
            .OrderBy(y => y.Index)
            .Skip(x.Index)
            .Combinations(combinationSize - 1)
            .Select(y => new[] { x }.Concat(y).Select(z => z.Item))
        );
}
```

The second method is from a [blog post by Eric Lippert](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2010/06/28/computing-a-cartesian-product-with-linq/) (which was actually inspired by another StackOverflow question), and looks like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> CartesianProduct<T>(this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> sequences)
{
    if (sequences == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(sequences));
    }

    IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> emptyProduct = new IEnumerable<T>[] { Enumerable.Empty<T>() };
    return sequences.Aggregate(
        emptyProduct,
        (accumulator, sequence) =>
            from accseq in accumulator
            from item in sequence
            select accseq.Concat(new[] { item }))
            .Where(x => x.Any());
}
```

The two methods can be combined like this:

```
var groupA = new[] { "a", "aa", "aaa", "aaaa", "aaaaa" };
var groupB = new[] { "b", "bb", "bbb", "bbbb", "bbbbb" };
var groupC = new[] { "c", "cc", "ccc", "cccc", "ccccc" };
var groupD = new[] { "d", "dd", "ddd", "dddd", "ddddd" };
var groupE = new[] { "e", "ee", "eee", "eeee", "eeeee" };
var groupF = new[] { "f", "ff", "fff", "ffff", "fffff" };

var options = new[]
{
    groupA.Combinations(1), // One object from groupA
    groupB.Combinations(2), // Two objects from groupB (no repetition)
    groupC.Combinations(3), // Three objects from groupC (no repetition)
    groupD.Combinations(1), // One object from groupD
    groupE.Combinations(1), // One object from groupE
    groupF.Combinations(1)  // One object from groupF
};

return options.CartesianProduct();
```

So, we generate the various ways of satisfying each of your sub-conditions first: one from this group, two from that group, etc. Then, we look at all ways of putting those together to form a group of subgroups. The result is an `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>` where `T` is the type of what you started with - in this case, `string`, but for you it could be something else. You can then iterate over this and use each set to build your result type.

Be aware that, like many combinatorial problems, this can scale quite fast. For example, with my test data this returns 62,500 possible combinations.